# Intellisense comments inside class functions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Is there any way to make C++ intellisense comments appear in the class member/function list when using it from within a class function in Visual Studio? Let me give an example.

Say we have a Dog and a Cat class like below. Let's assume the Cat has a "dog" reference to a Dog instance. Notice the Xml comments that have been added to each member function, specifically, the isBarking function for this example.

```
class Dog
{
    ///<summary>Makes the dog bark.</summary>
    void bark() { if (isBarking()) { /*woof woof*/ } }

    ///<summary>Is the dog barking?</summary>
    ///<return>This dog has no bark, so it always returns false.</return>
    bool isBarking() { return false; }
}

class Cat
{
    ///<summary>Should the cat run?</summary>
    ///<return>Always true if the dog is barking, otherwise false.</return>
    bool run() { return dog.isBarking(); }
}
```

When typing the isBarking function (or hovering your mouse over it) inside the Cat's run function, the intellisense summary and return comment for the isBarking function is displayed as per normal.

However, when typing the isBarking function (or hovering your mouse over it) inside the Dog's bark function, the intellisense summary and return comment is NOT displayed for the isBarking function. Is there anyway to get it to display?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio never displays `<return>` statements, they are meant for some other purpose. When you are extracting documentation out of your code, `<return>`s are used. Visual Studio displays `<summary>` statements only.

I just copied your code in VS 2013, I can see `<summary>` on mouse hover and while typing as well.
Just check your VS settings, Go to Visual Studio Editor, `Edit Menu-> Intellisense. To turn on/off Quick Info, Parameter Info, etc.`

Comment: I've realised that my example doesn't properly illustrate the problem. The problem occurs when the class definition and implementation are split between a .h and a .cpp file. So if the implementation of the Dog and Cat methods are moved to a .cpp file in my earlier example, then you'll hit the problem. You'll see that the summary comment is not shown for the isBarking function when typing it out inside the bark function for example.

Comment: I am using VS 2013 and I just carried out the exercise you mentioned. It does display the summary comments typing it inside Dog::bark function. Which VS edition are you using? I suggest you check settings, Go to Visual Studio Editor, Edit Menu-> Intellisense. To turn on/off Quick Info, Parameter Info, etc

Comment: VS 2013. Unfortunately, it doesn't work as you describe. I've tried hitting the Quick Info in the menu and it just shows the same thing in the tooltip without the summary. Is there anyway to post screen shots here? Maybe that might clear the problem up if I can show what is happening.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, I suggest you update VS 2013 installation, install all latest updates. See if that changes anything.